# R function that creates and references columns based upon input variables

Tags: r, function, paste

I am trying to create a function that will use input variables to create a new column and calculate said column based on subscripting values. In my example below I would like to create a column named 'forest_closed_start_h_1' which is calculated when start_class_01 == 'forest_closed' is equal to this formula: (start_class_01_perc * 0.01) * (ha_affect).

EDIT: I should have mentioned that I wanted a function (or even better, maybe a loop) because I have to calculate 50 different iterations of the same type of data.

This is the function I have written, but I cannot get the function variables to populate 'a', 'b', and 'c'. Nor can I get the function to create the new column.

```
class_calc <- function(start_end,number,veg){
  a <- [paste (veg,start_end,'h',number,sep='_')] #create new variable (a) equal to forest_closed_start_h_1
  b <- [paste0(start_end,'_class_',number)] #create new variable (b) equal to start_class_01
  c <- [paste0(start_end,'_class_',number,'_perc')] #create new variable (c) equal to start_class_01_perc
  dat$a <- 0 #create new column from variable a, which is forest_closed_start_h_01
  dat$a[dat$b==veg]<-(dat$c[dat$b==veg]*0.01)*(dat$ha_affect[dat$b==veg]) #calculate values for a, where start_class_01==forest_closed
}

class_calc(start_end='start',number='01',veg='forest_closed')
```

Here is a subset of my data:

```
structure(list(start_class_01 = c("forest_closed", "forest_closed", 
"forest_open", "forest_closed", "forest_closed", "forest_closed", 
"forest_closed", "forest_closed", "forest_closed", "forest_closed", 
"forest_closed", "forest_closed", "forest_closed", "forest_closed", 
"forest_closed", "forest_closed", "forest_closed", "forest_closed", 
"forest_closed", "forest_closed", "forest_closed", "forest_closed", 
"forest_closed", "forest_closed", "herbaceous", "forest_closed", 
"forest_closed", "forest_closed", "forest_closed", "forest_closed", 
"forest_closed", "forest_closed", "forest_semi_closed", "forest_closed", 
"forest_closed", "forest_closed", "forest_closed", "forest_closed", 
"forest_closed", "forest_closed", "forest_closed", "forest_closed", 
"forest_closed", "forest_closed", "forest_closed", "forest_closed", 
"forest_closed", "forest_closed", "forest_closed", "forest_closed"
), start_class_01_perc = c(100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 
100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 70, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 
100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 
100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 
100, 100, 100, 100), ha_affect = c(3.87, 1.134, 1.44, 1.8, 2.43, 
40.752, 22.95, 9.432, 1.89, 1.53, 2.25, 1.08, 8.946, 3.42, 3.15, 
4.32, 5.04, 1.62, 1.17, 2.16, 2.34, 25.56, 3.51, 2.07, 3.51, 
100.17, 15.66, 2.7, 36.27, 18.36, 4.41, 23.31, 1.944, 9.18, 1.62, 
5.76, 17.37, 7.56, 1.512, 81.36, 7.2, 61.02, 21.69, 1.62, 1.26, 
5.4, 0.288, 1.08, 7.74, 1.17)), .Names = c("start_class_01", 
"start_class_01_perc", "ha_affect"), row.names = c(NA, 50L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Hello, you seem to have `[` very awkwardly placed.  Perhaps you might want to brush up on the language syntax a bit?

Comment: The code you posted doesn't generate a valid function due to the syntax errors. You initialize `dat$a` but nowhere do you initialize `dat$b` or `dat$c` yet you use them in your question. Perhaps you just mean `b` and `c`.

Comment: It looks to me like you are trying to make your own version of existing functions.  have you seen `tapply`, `aggregate`, and the packages `plyr` and `dplyr`?

Comment: @MrFlick, you're right, the function doesn't work in its current form, but I was hoping it would provide a framework someone else could work from. Regarding dat$b and dat$c, I'm trying to refer to specific columns in the dataframe, but don't want to hardwire them into the function. Instead I thought I could define the specific column by pasting together parts of my function inputs. In the example provided I want dat$b defined as start_class_01, which is present in the dataframe and dat$c defined as start_class_01_perc, again already present in the dataframe. Hopefully this helps a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You can subsetd your data with `subset` (to get only closed forests) and then make a new column with `transform`.

```
dat1 <- subset(dat,dat$start_class_01 == "forest_closed")

dat1_new <- transform(dat1,forest_closed_start_h_1 = (start_class_01_perc * 0.01) * (ha_affect))

head(dat1_new)
  start_class_01 start_class_01_perc ha_affect forest_closed_start_h_1
1  forest_closed                 100     3.870                   3.870
2  forest_closed                 100     1.134                   1.134
4  forest_closed                 100     1.800                   1.800
5  forest_closed                 100     2.430                   2.430
6  forest_closed                 100    40.752                  40.752
7  forest_closed                 100    22.950                  22.950
```

If you want 0s where the forest class is **not** equal to "forest_closed", you can simply calculate your new column as above and then multiply by the logical vector you use to subset:

```
transform(dat,forest_closed_start_h_1 = (start_class_01_perc * 0.01) * (ha_affect) * (start_class_01 == "forest_closed"))

head(dat_new)
  start_class_01 start_class_01_perc ha_affect forest_closed_start_h_1
1  forest_closed                 100     3.870                   3.870
2  forest_closed                 100     1.134                   1.134
3    forest_open                 100     1.440                   0.000
4  forest_closed                 100     1.800                   1.800
5  forest_closed                 100     2.430                   2.430
6  forest_closed                 100    40.752                  40.752
```